# Force Spring Toolsuite to use maven-minify-plugin on hot redeploy

Tags: javascript, maven-2, minify, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

guys!

I'm stuck with the problem that looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311138/eclipse-sts-maven-and-maven-minify-plugin-can-they-work-together). I have changed generic lifecycle mapping to launch `minify` goal on resource change but still no luck.

Minifier launches but resulting files are placed into `[project folder]/target/[project_name]/resources/js` folder, and I need them to be in sts-tc server `wtpwebapps` folder. I know it's possible to change webappTargetDir parameter in the plugin configuration, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my generic lifecycle mapping settings:
`process-resources resources:testResources war:inplace minify:minify`

Here's the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-minify</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <jsSourceDir>resources/js</jsSourceDir>
                <jsTargetDir>resources/js</jsTargetDir>
                <jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsSourceFile>main.js</jsSourceFile>
                    <jsSourceFile>scripts.js</jsSourceFile>
                </jsSourceFiles>
                <jsFinalFile>final.js</jsFinalFile>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm new to Maven, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Mikhail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference url:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-samaxes-plugin/

jsTargetDir and jsSourceDir are both default to js so no need to include them or include an additional folder.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-minify</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <webappSourceDir>${js.src.dir}/resources</webappSourceDir>
            <webappTargetDir>${wtpwebapps.target.dir}/resources/</webappTargetDir>
            <jsSourceFiles>
                <jsSourceFile>main.js</jsSourceFile>
                <jsSourceFile>scripts.js</jsSourceFile>
            </jsSourceFiles>
            <jsFinalFile>final.js</jsFinalFile>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>minify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```